# How Use From HTMLAgilityPack For Finding A String in nested divs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, html-agility-pack, windows

there is an html codes like below :

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3">
  <div class="class4 class5">
    <span class="class6">GOAL STRING</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

now i want to find that `GOAL STRING` use from HTMLAgilityPack.
how can i do that?
[with **LINQ** and without **LINQ** = please show us both ways]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use xpath to get the span directly.

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='class1 class2 class3']/div[@class='class4 class5']/span[@class='class6']").InnerText;
```

This is a good resource for xpath specifically the table in the middle of the page:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Also on Google Chrome you can right click -> inspect element and then right click the element that shows up on the tree and click copy as Xpath to get a starting point. These expressions can usually be simplified.